# I need a regular expression to accept only strings that have sequences of a digit of length within a certain range

Tags: regex

I have a string containing a sequence of 1s and 0s. I need to define a regular expression such that no sequence of consecutive 1s can be longer than a variable *max* or shorter than a variable *min*. How would I go about this? Pretty new to regex.

Edit: Examples

If min were 2 and max were 4 the regex would accept:

110000111011110

and would not accept:

111110000000000 or 000010000100000

Comment: Some examples that match and others that don't would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this simple, assume max=7 and min=3.

```
^0*(1{3,7}(0+|$))*0*$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/RgT1UgbZk3dEZ9).

Answer (score 0):

This is an example regex to validate consecutive `1`s min 3 to max 7 times:

```
^(?!.*1{8})(?!(^|.*0)1{1,2}(0|$))
```

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor at start of string
- `(?!.*1{8})` - negative lookahead for a sequence of 8+ `1`s
- `(?!(^|.*0)1{1,2}(0|$))` - negative lookahead for sequence of up to 2 `1`s, preceded either by start of string or `0`, and suffixed by either a `0` or end of string